# Does VLC Player work well on Windows 7 64-bit?

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I tried VLC Player on Windows 7 64-bit version and the playback was fine, but when the video is maximized the image is very pixelated. I tried this on a Radeon HD 2600 XT graphics card as well as a computer with an Intel graphics chipset and both have the same result.

If I use VLC Player on Windows 7 32-bit instead of 64-bit, there is no pixelation.

Is this a known problem or is there any method to fix it on Windows 7 64-bit?

**Update:** there isn't a 32-bit vs 64-bit version of VLC player, is there?  (unlike 7-Zip)

I also tried GOM Player and it doesn't have the problem on Windows 7 64-bit.

**Update: Nov 4, 2009**

> VLC displays an update notice:
>
> VLC 1.0.3 is a minor release fixing
>   many bugs, especially for Windows Vista
>   and 7, but it also introduces 2 new
>   modes for deinterlacing, and a new
>   udev module. Major fixes are about WMA
>   Pro support, Dolby tracks in 4.0,
>   v4l/v4l2 and atsc and a crash in mjpeg
>   demuxer. Update of translations are
>   also part of this release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were issues with Windows 7 and VLC with pixelation.
One workaround was to switch the video renderer (didn't work for me).

However if you use the latest build of VLC then you will find the issue has been fixed.
I'm using Windows 7 RTM 64bit and VLC 1.0.3 RC.  I have a Radeon HD4870.

ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/testing/vlc-1.0.3-rc/win32/

Comment: great to know someone saw the same issue.

Comment: this is the message on VLC's website: VLC 1.0.3 Release Candidate and Windows 7
2009-10-22
The VLC developers are very glad to offer you the first release candidate of the third minor update of the popular "Goldeneye" version of VLC.
This version brings a few improvements and fixes, and especially fixes an important issue with Windows® 7 that worsened the video quality of the default output of VLC. As Windows® 7 will be available today, the windows maintainers of VLC wanted to sync with this release.

Answer (score 7):

It works fine for me - 1400x900 laptop screen, 1920x1080 tv and 1280x1024 secondary screen.

The problems you are having may be down to either the graphics drivers or source video, however I have not seen anything that would lead me to believe I have any problems with VLC itself.

[image]

Comment: I've had no problems getting it to work on 4 different computers at home, all running Win7 RC.

Comment: Works for me with Win7 Home Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

as a staunch vlc user/supporter, i've recently switched over to the gom player.  i've been extremely happy with it.  you may want to give that a shot on your 7 box just as a test to see if the issue is with the video player or some other issue(drivers or source as mentioned by wil)....

edited to include [link](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/GMP_download.html) to gom player

Comment: GOM Player ... do they still install some browser toolbar? ^^

Comment: not from what i remember.  i did have to install two codecs on my own to play a dvd(which gom player actually pointed me to so i didn't have to figure it out on my own), so it's not a 'complete' package.  but, like i said, i'm really happy with it.

Comment: not dissing GOM pre se, it's quite nice actually, but at some stage they wanted to install a browser toolbar (google IIRC) by default, and that's a No No in my books.

Comment: i'll be running through the install again tonight to put it on my home pc, i'll let you know for sure then.  but, honestly, i only installed this a couple days ago and i don't remember them trying to sneak that in.  like you, i despise software that tries to sneak in extra installs like that....

Answer (score 0):

The latest update fixes the pixelization issue. I was also having that problem. I used KM Player for a while until the update came.

Update your VLC Player.

EDIT: I also use Win7 64.